# Django debugger hangs in settings.py - Runs fine

Tags: python, django, debugging

I can't debug custom_commands in django anymore. I try it with PyCharm (tried it with VSCode as well) using the template for Django Server and entering my custom command. If I hit *run* on this configuration it is running fine. If I try to debug it hangs after printing the graylog configuration.

I could debug it from the `settings.py` until it is in `venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py` in the function `import_module` where it tries to execute the command `_bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)` and from that on it hangs. Unfortunately I can't share the repository.

The same thing happens with other custom commands as well.

If I look at the trace with `-m trace --trace` I'll see that it gets stuck in `threading.py`. This is the last output:

```py
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: _release_save
threading.py(249):         self._lock.release()           # No state to save
threading.py(292):         gotit = False
threading.py(293):         try:    # restore state no matter what (e.g., KeyboardInterrupt)
threading.py(294):             if timeout is None:
threading.py(298):                 if timeout > 0:
threading.py(299):                     gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
```

Any ideas for that problem?

Comment: try reinstalling the virtualenvironment and the packages

Comment: I tried it with another virtual environment but I run into the same problem.

Comment: You have a missing module then in your project that's why read the output further
somewhere you should have something like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework`

Comment: I don't get any output messages it just hangs. And then it shouldn't run normally without debugging right? I checked it, `rest_framework` is installed.

Comment: I ment any package not the rest_framework, it was an example can you Show the output of the console?

Comment: I don't get any output messages except for some print statements at the beginning of `setup.py`